# Flash: Pagination with XML

Tags: xml, flash, pagination, paging, actionscript-2

(working in AS2.0 due to player limitations)

In my flash application I draw in data from an XML. This data is for example 6 lines long in 1 language, but could be 20 in a different language.

However the textbox on the screen can only populate 10 lines of text and I'd like to give the option to users to press the arrows to go to the next page (if there is a next page).

What are my options to get this 'page'-effect?

Comment: You can't use scrolling instead? Scrolling is a much better user option for small amounts of text than pagination is.

Comment: Scrolling is sadly not an option + this is just an example. The end-xml will be texts of about 200 lines for each chapter. (for 1 language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure out the roundabout total of characters that can fit per page. Then use substring to get the text for each page until you reach the end of the xml string. Put each page string into an array and just change the text in the textfield when the user clicks the arrow using an iterator type pattern.

Edit based on comment:

Ah I see what you are saying. Well here's a more brute force, character-by-character method to creating an array of textfields at or around a specified height.

```
var pageIndex = 0;
var maxHeight = 300;
var copy = "Some super long chunk of text here";

var pages = [];

function parsePages()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < copy.length; i++)
    {
        if(pages.length == 0) createPage(0);

        pages[pageIndex].text += copy.charAt(i);
        pages[pageIndex]._height = pages[pageIndex].textHeight;

        if(pages[pageIndex]._height >= maxHeight)
        {
            pageIndex++;
            createPage(pageIndex);
        }
    }
}

function createPage(index)
{
    this.createTextField("page_"+index,this.getNextHighestDepth(),0,0,300,12);
    this["page_"+index].multiline = true;
    this["page_"+index].wordWrap = true;
    this["page_"+index].font = "Arial";
    this["page_"+index].size = 10;
    this["page_"+index].text = "";

    pages.push(this["page_"+index]);
}

parsePages();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I've been trying to do this, however a single arabic character could be wider then a "normal" letter. However I would use this approach if I'd only have to create it in 1 language.

Comment: On edit: Wow, that's quite a heavy process. Tried it and worked... thx a lot.